# how to select element from different divs of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here, on change of a dropdown (values 1-100), the selected number of `<tr>` clones it will add on. I have tried to utilize a couple different variations of selectors, but Im missing something. When I run this code, and a user changes the dropdown in the top div, it adds fields to the second div. I know it is because the classes are the same, how couldve I cloned these to make the divs be separate from each other? The div "NewTeam" is created by cloning based on a selection made earlier.

I would like the dropdown in a given div to only add rows to the table in the same div. Keep in mind that based on the users input, there could be more than two div with class **newTeam**

Appreciate the help!

```
  $(".RosterCountSelect").change(function(){
    var numOfPlayers = this.value;
    c=$('.PlayerRow').length; //How many rows are already shown?
    for (var i = c; i < numOfPlayers; i++){ 
        $(".PlayerRow").first().clone().insertAfter(".PlayerRow:last"); 
    }
});
```

HTML Markup

```
 <div class="newTeam">
 <fieldset class="vfb-fieldset vfb-fieldset-1 str8-sports-roster-upload " id="TeamFieldset" style = "display: none">
  <div class="vfb-legend">
     <h4 style="padding-left: 40px;">New Team - <input class = "TeamName" style = "width:200px" type = "text" placeholder = "Team Name (eg: Girls 5th Grade)"/></h4>
     <label>Roster Count:</label><select class="RosterCountSelect">
     </select>
     <form>
        <table>
           <tr class = "PlayerRow">
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Full Name" /></td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Number" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Jersey Size" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Short Size" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Male/Female" /> </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </form>
  </div>
</fieldset>
 </div>
 <div class="newTeam">
 <fieldset class="teamInfo" id= "TeamFieldset">
  <div class="vfb-legend">
     <h4 style="padding-left: 40px;">New Team - <input class = "TeamName" style = "width:200px" type = "text" placeholder = "Team Name (eg: Girls 5th Grade)"/></h4>
     <label>Roster Count:</label><select class="RosterCountSelect">
     </select>
     <form>
        <table>
           <tr class = "PlayerRow">
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Full Name" /></td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Number" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Jersey Size" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Short Size" /> </td>
              <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Male/Female" /> </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </form>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: `#PlayerInfoTable` and `#TeamName` twice inside a single document? Let's get back to HTML markup basics.

Comment: sorry. see edits please

Comment: you still have duplicate `#TeamFieldset` and it's still not clear from which div the elements should be cloned. When I paste your code into jsBin I see nothing (due to display:none etc...) also there are empty select boxes. It's your job to create a minimal but testable code in order to get a reliable and fast help.

Comment: also please please avoid `id = ""` use `id=""` it's more readable. Also, avoid using inline styles (same goes for inline JS). Keep styles and program logic away from the HTML skelet.

Answer (score 1):

You can select only one class use to allay.

```
$($('.newTeam')[0])
$($('.newTeam')[1])
...
```

I'm not sure,but try this one.

```
  $(".RosterCountSelect").change(function(){
    var numOfPlayers = this.value;
    var playerRow = $(this).parent('.newTeam').children('.PlayerRow');
    var playerRowlast = $(this).parent('.newTeam').children('.PlayerRow:last');
    c=playerRow.length; //How many rows are already shown?
    for (var i = c; i < numOfPlayers; i++){ 
        playerRow.first().clone().insertAfter(playerRowlast); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont understand. I can create an array of $(".newTeam")? Or does the DOM create one when cloned?

Comment: I think, you want to like this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hakegehucu/1/edit?html,output)